# <video> plays in other browsers, but not in Brave

Tags: html5-video, brave, brave-browser

The video is a simple MP4.  It works if I open it in it's own tab in Brave and I have checked and verified that Brave itself it not blocking it.

The server does support "Range" Requests and the video works in Safari.

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="image.jpg" class="w-100">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The poster does work and it shows in brave but the video will not play.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Brave also:

```
<div>
    <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" src="video.mp4"></video>
</div>
```